# Suggest a book of statistics for a pure mathematician.

Tags: book-recommendation

I have looked into Walpole and Devore, but I am not being able to decide. I want to study probability and statistics (both are my weak points) to be able to clear interviews and qualifying tests. I am a pure mathematician with knowledge of both pure and applied maths.
Please suggest between these two or recommend any other book.

Comment: Statistics is a vast field; you should narrow down your question to something more specific. Said another way: if a statistician asked "which book should I read to learn pure maths", what would you respond?

Comment: Maybe [**Introduction to Mathematical Statistics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0134686993) by Robert Vincent Hogg and Allen Thornton Craig [Joseph McKean added beginning with 2005 6th edition] (1959, 1965, 1970, 1978, 1995, 2005, 2013, 2019). The 1978 4th edition was used for a popular 2-semester elective course by math graduate students when I was at Indiana University (1982-84), although I didn't take it myself (I did buy a copy of the text however), and it seems to be fairly widely used and well known. Only Riemann integration is used, no measure theory or Lebesgue integration is needed.